# Hosting Private Git repos on my own server?

Tags: git

I am looking for a way to host private git repos on my own server.
I am using Github for Open source projects of mine, but I would prefer to use my own server for storing private git repos.

Can someone suggest me on which script should I be using for this purpose.
Trac is not what I am looking for, though. I want something that is, preferably PHP based solution (just optional) and esp. something that has an easier UI.

Any help is appreciated here.

Comment: wouldn't this be better suited for serverfault?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, for non-gitosis/gitorious setup you have two options really:

1. Give people linux accounts with full shells (passwords and/or ssh keys) to have access to the git repository.
2. Give people access to a linux account via their ssh key being in `/home/ac/.ssh/authorized_keys2` whose shell is set to `/usr/bin/git-shell`. This means they won't be able to log in as a linux user with a shell and so do anything except use git on your machine.

In both cases, the user in question needs (read|write|both) access to the git repository, according to your needs, either as a user or as part of a group.

It might make sense for you to have a directory /git/project and then have user repositories in there, as having multiple people pushing to the same repository is generally a bad idea (people break things too easily in my experience). For example, you might have `/srv/git/proj/proj-ninefingers.git` and have a "release" repo of '/srv/git/proj/project.git` That's probably what I'd do if running a team effort. Permissions, shells etc to be set as appropriate.

Note that if you want to allow exports via the read-only git protocol you need to ensure the configured git user has read access and that `git-daemon-export-ok` exists in your bare repository. `git update-server-info` must also be run before `gitweb` will pick up the repository, should you wish to use that.

As others have said, `git gc` optimises the repository and it is a good idea to do this regularly. Cron job?

Finally, a plethora of frameworks exist to simplify this (gitosis, gitorious, ...). I don't think it gets any simpler than providing access to a folder via various mechanisms but then that's me.

As an example of my setup, it being only me, I have:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep git
git:x:1002:1002:Antony Vennard,,,:/home/git:/usr/bin/git-shell
gitdaemon:x:112:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false
$ cat /etc/group | grep git
git:x:1002:
$ ls -l /srv/git
drwxr-xr-x 7 git  git 4096 2010-09-12 23:31 bsdnt.git
drwxr-xr-x 7 git  git 4096 2010-06-16 22:32 vforth.git
$ cat /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys2
ssh-rsa somehex user1
ssh-rsa somehex user2
```

This means anyone with the private key user1 can log in and commit to either of those repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Never tried it myself, but gitorious hosts the code their running on:

- http://gitorious.org/gitorious

Another option with gitosis:

- http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way

Answer (score 1):

[Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) is based on there own codebase.
On [this page](http://gitorious.org/gitorious) you can find the git-repo. of the project.

[Gitalist](http://www.gitalist.com/) is very easy to use git Webinterface.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the code repository and no web pages, just place the ".git" directory somewhere accessible, that is sufficient for cloning via HTTP (note that you will need ssh or similar to push to that repository).

For example, a project of mine is hosted this way at http://psi5.com/~geier/mutextrace.git .

It is a good idea to periodically run "git gc" on that repository in order to pack objects together, so clients don't have to make thousands of accesses.

If you want web pages, then gitorious is indeed the way to go.